# MapBox Android SDK 2.2.0 - How create custom marker with an area of a specified radius

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

In my project(minSdkVersion 15), I use MapBox Android SDK 2.2.0. I need to create a marker at the center point of which will be written the number and circle around a certain radius. I tried to resolve this issue by writing a Drawable, then instead of

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_directions_boat_black_18dp);
```

write

```
MyCuStomDrawable myCustomDrawable = new MyCuStomDrawable();

SpriteFactory spriteFactory = new SpriteFactory(mapView);
Sprite icon = spriteFactory.fromDrawable(myCustomDrawable);

mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-33.8500000, 18.4158234))
                .title("My Marker")
                .icon(icon));
```

But Marker adds an icon to the default.
How do I solve this problem?

Update:
I need to create like this:
[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrfMP.jpg)   [Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QRM6.jpg)

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with `adds an icon`? could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I've added an example of a marker with dynamic trigger. See [Screen 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GrfMP.jpg) and [Screen 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7QRM6.jpg). I need to do the same marker.

Comment: Currently the Mapbox SDK does not expose an API like that. The markers are GL-draw components. The shown screens look a lot like the `UserLocationView` which is a Android View on top of Mapview but their is no generic system for having your own View style Markers. Theoretically it is feasible to do so. I will ticket this out in the Mapbox issue tracker

Comment: If have added a feature request for above in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3276

Comment: Is it possible if i could create a circle bitmap dynamically changing its radius base on map zoom and convert it to icon to be as part of a marker?

I need help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473515/building-custom-overlay-specifically-circle-with-radiuscolored-in-android-mapb

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sprite icon = spriteFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_directions_boat_black_18dp);
```

Comment: Scott, your solution does not fit into the specified problem me. You provide a simple example of the use of resources, and I need to dynamically create.