# Mapbox touchlistner for map

Tags: android, mapbox

Hi I am using mapbox to display map in android app. I'm stuck in a situation where I need to get radius of a map that is visible to the user. if user zoom-in or zoom-out the radius of the map changes. Can anyone tell me how do I do this or suggest me any reference link regarding this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473515/building-custom-overlay-specifically-circle-with-radiuscolored-in-android-mapb refer this stack blog,may be you will get some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect when the map scale has changed you need to add a listener to the `MapboxMap`. Here's an example of a class that extends `MapView` to add a scale bar at the bottom that dynamically resizes as the map is zoomed or panned (panning will change the scale in distance, but not in degrees.) This is what it looks like:

[image: example of scale bar on Mapbox]

A couple of points: the only way to get the `MapboxMap` from the `MapView` is to request it asynchronously. The Activity or Fragment hosting the map should do that. This class overrides `getMapAsync()` to allow it to also get a reference to the `MapboxMap` but the hosting Activity still needs to call that method.

Camera change events are reported to a listener, and only one can be set at at time on the `MapboxMap` so if the hosting activity has a listener, it should call `ScaledMapView#onCameraChange()` in that listener's similarly named method.

The `MapView` itself must be contained in a `FrameLayout` to enable the scale view to be added.

Obviously you could simply incorporate the same basic code in your Activity or Fragment, and include the scale TextView in the layout rather than adding it programmatically.

The extended class:

```
package com.controlj.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLngBounds;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMapOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by clyde on 2/10/2016.
 * This class extends the Mapbox Mapview to add a scale at the bottom
 */

public class ScaledMapview extends MapView implements MapboxMap.OnCameraChangeListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
    private TextView scaleText;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private OnMapReadyCallback callback;
    private ScaleUnit scaleUnit = ScaleUnit.KM;
    private float labelWidth = 0.33f;

    public float getLabelWidth() {
        return labelWidth;
    }

    public void setLabelWidth(float labelWidth) {
        if(labelWidth > 1f)
            labelWidth = 1f;
        else if(labelWidth < 0.1f)
            labelWidth = 0.1f;
        this.labelWidth = labelWidth;
    }

    public ScaleUnit getScaleUnit() {
        return scaleUnit;
    }

    public void setScaleUnit(ScaleUnit scaleUnit) {
        this.scaleUnit = scaleUnit;
    }

    enum ScaleUnit {
        MILE("mile", 1609.344f),
        NM("nm", 1852.0f),
        KM("km", 1000.0f);

        ScaleUnit(String unit, float ratio) {
            this.unit = unit;
            this.ratio = ratio;
        }

        String unit;
        float ratio;
    }

    public ScaledMapview(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScaledMapview(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScaledMapview(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public ScaledMapview(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable MapboxMapOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
    }

    @Override
    public void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        super.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * To ensure this is called when the camera changes, either this ScaledMapview must be passed
     * to mapboxMap.setOnCameraChangeListener() or whatever is listening must also call this method
     * when it is called.
     *
     * @param position The CameraPosition at the end of the last camera change.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        if (scaleText == null) {
            ViewParent v = getParent();
            if (v instanceof FrameLayout) {
                scaleText = (TextView)inflate(getContext(), R.layout.mapscale, null);
                ((FrameLayout)v).addView(scaleText);
            }
        }
        if (scaleText != null) {
            // compute the horizontal span in metres of the bottom of the map
            LatLngBounds latLngBounds = mapboxMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
            float span[] = new float[1];
            Location.distanceBetween(latLngBounds.getLatSouth(), latLngBounds.getLonEast(),
                    latLngBounds.getLatSouth(), latLngBounds.getLonWest(), span);

            float totalWidth = span[0] / scaleUnit.ratio;
            // calculate an initial guess at step size
            float tempStep = totalWidth * labelWidth;

            // get the magnitude of the step size
            float mag = (float)Math.floor(Math.log10(tempStep));
            float magPow = (float)Math.pow(10, mag);

            // calculate most significant digit of the new step size
            float magMsd = (int)(tempStep / magPow + 0.5);

            // promote the MSD to either 1, 2, or 5
            if (magMsd > 5.0f)
                magMsd = 10.0f;
            else if (magMsd > 2.0f)
                magMsd = 5.0f;
            else if (magMsd > 1.0f)
                magMsd = 2.0f;
            float length = magMsd * magPow;
            if (length >= 1f)
                scaleText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.0f %s", length, scaleUnit.unit));
            else
                scaleText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f %s", length, scaleUnit.unit));
            // set the total width to the appropriate fraction of the display
            int width = Math.round(getWidth() * length / totalWidth);
            LayoutParams layoutParams =
                    new LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = 4;
            scaleText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        // if the owner of this view is listening for the map, pass it through. If not, we must
        // listen for camera events ourselves.
        if (callback != null)
            callback.onMapReady(mapboxMap);
        else
            mapboxMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
        onCameraChange(null);
    }
}
```

The Activity:

```
package com.controlj.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapboxAccountManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    ScaledMapview mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnStart()");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate()");
        MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (ScaledMapview)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnPause()");
        mapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnResume()");
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnSaveInstanceState()");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

The activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.controlj.test.MainActivity">

        <com.controlj.test.ScaledMapview
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:access_token="@string/mapbox_access_token"
            mapbox:center_latitude="-31.42166667"
            mapbox:center_longitude="152.75833333"
            mapbox:style_url="@string/mapbox_style"
            mapbox:zoom="4"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the layout for the scale widget itself. The image resource `@drawable/scale` is a 9-patch image file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scale_text"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/scale"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="100km"/>
```

Comment: i'm sorry for late reply because this task has been put on hold but i will let you know which answer worked for me as soon as i will resume the task. Anyway many thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the assumption that by radius you mean the map distance currently visible to the user? if this is the case, you can get the absolute distance, in degrees, between the west and east boundaries.

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = mapboxMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
latLngBounds.getLongitudeSpan();
```

Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: :- ok can you guide me regarding how do i implement touch-listeners to detect zoom-in, zoom-out action of user on map.

Comment: You can use `mapboxMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new MapboxMap.OnCameraChangeListener()` which gives the updated camera position. From this you can get the current zoom.